# Trying to understand the behavior of splitting partitions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to understand the behavior of splitting partitions during the amount of storage.

I have a table with **50 read capacity units** and **50 write capacity units** with **storage of 9.99GB**.

As i can see from documentation, when data grow to **10GB**, it will split the parition to 2 partitions (**25 read and write capacity units**, **5GB storage for each**).

If i change the read capacity units to **500**, each partition will have **250 read capcity units**? or it will split the partitions to **4 partitions**? (for example):

- parition1: 25 read
- parition2: 25 read
- parition3: 225 read
- parition4: 225 read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RCUs and WCUs (Read/Write Capacity Units) are always equally divided among all partitions.

So, to answer your question, you'll end up with 2 partitions, each with 250 and 25 RCUs and WCUs respectively.